# SQLite Set max rows or just update the same one?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Just a simple question for SQLite while using it in Android. I want to have a database with only one row. Should I just set the max rows = 1 or should I just update the same row? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the same row makes the most sense because, seemingly if the same row was overwritten (because only one row was allowed), it would not update the fields, it would just replace them.